# How to set up th width without disturbing td

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a code where I'm creating a table in HTML. And my challenge is, if I try to get the header (time range) in one line by increasing the width, the width of tds are also changing. Here is my code.

```html
<table style="border:1px solid #8c8c8c;width:100%;border:1px solid #8c8c8c;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;margin-bottom:1.5em">
  <thead>
    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;background-color:#e9e9e9;font-size:16px">
      <th width="24%">
        <div style="width:auto">10:35PM - 11:05PM (30 MIN)</div>
      </th>
      <th style="text-align:right;padding-right:1em;margin-right:1em;" height="40px;">John Williams</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline" style="width:15%;padding-left:0.5em;">
        <div style="line-height:2em;font-weight:bold"> Topic:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline">
        <div>Resume Review</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline" style="width:15%;padding-left:0.5em">
        <div style="line-height:2em;font-weight:bold">Phone:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline">123445567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline" style="width:15%;padding-left:0.5em">
        <div style="line-height:2em;font-weight:bold">Email:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline"><a href="mailto:JUDYRODRIGUEZ583@GMAIL.COM" target="_blank">JWillia@GMAIL.COM</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline">
        <div style="line-height:2em;width:auto;font-weight:bold">Student notes:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline"> some junk test text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note**: I'm not allowed to use an external CSS file. How can I fix this?

Comment: does adding `colspan="2"` give you what you want? `<th width="24%" colspan="2" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want first cells of different width, they need to span different amount of columns, else it will fill only one column.

You have a 2 column table, via colspan, you may turn it into a 3 columns.

thead : `<th colspan="2">th 24%</th><th> use space left </th>` = 3 columns with the first cell going through 2 columns

tbody : `<td>15%</td><td colspan="2"> space left</td>` = 3 columns again.

The second column will be 24% - 15%  = 9% wich will be used by the cell spanning through 2 columns.

theorie in action ;) :

```html
<table style="border:1px solid #8c8c8c;width:100%;border:1px solid #8c8c8c;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;margin-bottom:1.5em">
  <thead>
    <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;background-color:#e9e9e9;font-size:16px">
      <th width="24%" colspan="2">
        <div style="width:auto">10:35PM - 11:05PM (30 MIN)</div>
      </th>
      <th style="text-align:right;padding-right:1em;margin-right:1em;" height="40px;">John Williams</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline" style="width:15%;padding-left:0.5em;">
        <div style="line-height:2em;font-weight:bold"> Topic:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline" colspan="2">
        <div>Resume Review</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline" style="width:15%;padding-left:0.5em">
        <div style="line-height:2em;font-weight:bold">Phone:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline" colspan="2">123445567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline" style="width:15%;padding-left:0.5em">
        <div style="line-height:2em;font-weight:bold">Email:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline" colspan="2"><a href="mailto:JUDYRODRIGUEZ583@GMAIL.COM" target="_blank">JWillia@GMAIL.COM</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="baseline">
        <div style="line-height:2em;width:auto;font-weight:bold">Student notes:</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="baseline" colspan="2"> some junk test text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, buddy. This was exactly what I needed.